# How to put fileDownload inside a p:dataGrid header?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2, datagrid, download

I have searched a lot but I couldn't find the solution of my problem:

I'm just using primefaces and I want to use a fileDownload(button or link or icon) **inside the header of a dataGrid**.
If it's not possible any other suggestions would be appreciated.

my code is working properly right now but when I put fileDownload inside the grid it stops working.

Thanks in advance.

my code is something like this :

```
 <p:commandButton id="export" icon="fa fa-file-excel-o" value="#{msg['tweets']}" ajax="false" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(start, stop);"
                                                        rendered="#{localTwitterBean.tweetInfoList.size()>0}">

        <p:fileDownload value="#{localTwitterBean.exporter.getTweetsExcelDocument(localTwitterBean.tweetInfoList)}"/>

 </p:commandButton>

 <p:dataGrid id="tweets" var="tweet" value="#{localTwitterBean.tweetInfoList}" columns="1">
      <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/include/tweet_list.xhtml">
          <ui:param name="checkboxValue" value="#{localTwitterBean.exporter.exportCheckbox[tweet.id]}"/>
          <ui:param name="renderCheckbox" value="true"/>
      </ui:include>
 </p:dataGrid>
```

Comment: Have you tried to use <f:facet name="header"> </facet> in your dataGrid and placed the button inside?

Comment: @lastresort yes, I did . I even tried with commandLink but there was no success...